# call to member function prepare error

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, fatal-error

I am having an issue executing the below code. I get an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs... everytime I run it. It errors out right when it is about to query the database for some reason.

I am creating a function to check a username and password, and if it matches, log the user in and so forth. What I am trying to do is feed the outer function a username and a password, then pass those variables to the inner function (checkUser) to retrieve the user and password. Once I have those in an array, I want to compare to see if they match. If they do, then I want to continue on (I left the rest out for simplicity's sake). I don't know why I am getting the error I am getting, especially since it won't even run the 3rd line in the CheckUser without a fatal error.

This is homework, fyi, cards on the table. Just trying to get past this part. Thanks for any help.

```
function isValidUser($username, $password){
     $checker = checkUser($username, $password);
     if ($checker[user_email] == $username && $checker[user_pwd] == $password ) {
         return TRUE;
     }

 }

function checkUser($username, $password) {
    global $db;
    $st = $db -> prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email = ? and user_pwd = ?;');
    $st -> bindParam(1, $username);
    $st -> bindParam(2, $password);
    $st -> execute();
    return $st -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead of `global $db`

```
$db = $GLOBALS['db'];
```

Comment: That didn't fix the issue, I got another error along with the other one, that says Notice: Undefined index: db

Comment: Should $db be initialized after it passes that line? For whatever reason, in my debugger, it shows as uninitialized...maybe that is the issue?

Comment: So, I'm an idiot, and forgot the include_once for my DB file that connects to my database. Thanks for your comment, wouldn't have found it without you!